# Django Rest Framework -Serializer inside serializer using same instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

So, I have a weird legacy issue where I have one model "Data", and for serialization purposes I need to restructure the fields.

```py
class Data(models.Model):
   id ...
   field_a
   field_b
   field_c
   date
```

Then I have the serializers:

```
class DataInfoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = ['field_a', 'field_b', 'field_c']


class DataSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    data_info = DataInfoSerializer(required=False, read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = ['id', 'date', 'data_info']
```

Now I somehow have to get DRF to use the same instance of Data that is passed into the "DataSerializer" to render the DataInfoSerializer.

Any ideas how to achieve this? Or a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `source='*'` to pass the entire object to a field, including nested serializers. [Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)

```
class DataSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    data_info = DataInfoSerializer(required=False, read_only=True, source='*')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = ['id', 'date', 'data_info']
```

Comment: Perfect, I must have missed the part where you can pass * into source.. Thanks mate